# What's a more efficient implementation of this puzzle?

Tags: algorithm, puzzle

**The puzzle**

For every input number n (n < 10) there is an output number m such that:

- m's first digit is n
- m is an n digit number
- every 2 digit sequence inside m must be a different prime number

The output should be m where m is the smallest number that fulfils the conditions above. If there is no such number, the output should be -1;

**Examples**

n = 3 -> m = 311

n = 4 -> m = 4113 (note that this is not 4111 as that would be repeating 11)

n = 9 -> m = 971131737

**My somewhat working solution**

Here's my first stab at this, the "brute force" approach. I am looking for a more elegant solution as this is very inefficient as n grows larger.

```
public long GetM(int n)
{
    long start = n * (long)Math.Pow((double)10, (double)n - 1);
    long end = n * (long)Math.Pow((double)10, (double)n);
    for (long x = start; x < end; x++)
    {
        long xCopy = x;
        bool allDigitsPrime = true;
        List<int> allPrimeNumbers = new List<int>();
        while (xCopy >= 10)
        {
            long lastDigitsLong = xCopy % 100;
            int lastDigits = (int)lastDigitsLong;
            bool lastDigitsSame = allPrimeNumbers.Count != 0 && allPrimeNumbers.Contains(lastDigits);
            if (!IsPrime(lastDigits) || lastDigitsSame)
            {
                allDigitsPrime = false;
                break;
            }

            xCopy /= 10;
            allPrimeNumbers.Add(lastDigits);
        }

        if (n != 1 && allDigitsPrime)
        {
            return x;
        }
    }

    return -1;
}
```

**Initial thoughts on how this could be made more efficient**

So, clearly the bottleneck here is traversing through the whole list of numbers that could fulfil this condition from n.... to (n+1).... . Instead of simply incrementing the number of every iteration of the loop, there must be some clever way of skipping numbers based on the requirement that the 2 digit sequences must be prime. For instance for n = 5, there is no point going through 50000 - 50999 (50 isn't prime), 51200 - 51299 (12 isn't prime), but I wasn't quite sure how this could be implemented or if it would be enough of an optimization to make the algorithm run for n=9.

Any ideas on this approach or a different optimization approach?

Comment: n = 4 -> m = 971131737, seems wrong. Did you mean n = 9 -> m = 971131737?

Comment: The requirement of every 2 digit sequence inside m must be a different prime number - limits the size of N to 25 (the number of prime numbers under 100)
Therefore - I would suggest to hardcode it :)

Comment: yes, good spot @sara :) Hmm, that's a good idea, maybe you can generate m using a list of prime numbers, as opposed to the other way around. Thanks! :)

Comment: There are no that many 2-digit prime numbers, you can precompute them all. You also know which digits may follow any given digit in the sequence. Now you just need to find a path in a maze of digits.

Comment: I would make a list of primes, then add onto a number based on the current last number.  Could be done with recursion.  n = 1 is a special case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a possible solution, in R, using recursion .  It would be interesting to build a tree of all the possible paths

```
# For every input number n (n < 10) 
# there is an output number m such that:

#  m's first digit is n
#  m is an n digit number
#  every 2 digit sequence inside m must be a different prime number
# Need to select the smallest m that meets the criteria

library('numbers')

mNumHelper <- function(cn,n,pr,cm=NULL)  {
  if (cn == 1) {
    if (n==1) {
      return(1)
    }
    firstDigit <- n
  } else {
    firstDigit <- mod(cm,10)
  }
  possibleNextNumbers <- pr[floor(pr/10) == firstDigit]
  nPossible = length(possibleNextNumbers)
  if (nPossible == 1) {
    nextPrime <- possibleNextNumbers
  } else{
    # nextPrime <- sample(possibleNextNumbers,1)
    nextPrime <- min(possibleNextNumbers)
  }
  pr <- pr[which(pr!=nextPrime)] 
  if (is.null(cm)) {
    cm <- nextPrime
  } else {
    cm = cm * 10 + mod(nextPrime,10)
  }
  cn = cn + 1
  if (cn < n) {
    cm = mNumHelper(cn,n,pr,cm)
  }
  return(cm)
}

mNum <- function(n) {
  pr<-Primes(10,100)
  m <- mNumHelper(1,n,pr)  
}
for (i in seq(1,9)) {
  print(paste('i',i,'m',mNum(i)))
}
```

Sample output

```
[1] "i 1 m 1"
[1] "i 2 m 23"
[1] "i 3 m 311"
[1] "i 4 m 4113"
[1] "i 5 m 53113"
[1] "i 6 m 611317"
[1] "i 7 m 7113173"
[1] "i 8 m 83113717"
[1] "i 9 m 971131737"
```

Solution updated to select the smallest prime from the set of available primes, and remove bad path check since it's not required.

Comment: "i 3 m 317" doesn't look correct to me. The question already shows that the correct output for 3 is 311, not 317, and by my reading of the requirements, I agree that the correct output is 311.

Comment: Yep, looks like all the answers are wrong apart from n = 2. I'm a bit unsure that the backtracking part works, when you're on the wrong path you call return(mNum(n)), how does that call different from the initial one? 

I suspect that code path is not being hit as I have an iterative implementation of this and there is no need for backtrack for n < 10 :)

Comment: @hvd for n = 3, a result is 317, the first digit is 3, it's a 3 digit number, and the 2 digit sequences are 31 and 17, both prime. Where is the error?  Every number meets the three criteria.  The reason mNum(n) differs is because the sampling is random, so every run could give a different set of solutions.  The easy problem to see is when n is 9, the only prime is 97, so then none of the other primes selected can end in 9 since there isn't a 2nd prime that starts with 9.

Comment: @Metro101 Can you identify one number that doesn't met the three criteria?

Comment: @John "The output should be m where m is the smallest number that fulfils the conditions above." 311 is a smaller number than 317 that fulfills the conditions.

Comment: This is an "easy" fix, just change the random selection to select the lowest prime from the set of available....

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to try all numbers. You can instead use a different strategy, summed up as "try appending a digit".

Which digit? Well, a digit such that

1. it forms a prime together with your current last digit
2. the prime formed has not occurred in the number before

This should be done recursively (not iteratively), because you may run out of options and then you'd have to backtrack and try a different digit earlier in the number.

This is still an exponential time algorithm, but it avoids most of the search space because it never tries any numbers that don't fit the rule that every pair of adjacent digits must form a prime number.

Comment: Yes, this is the correct approach, worked like a charm with an iterative approach (seems to work for n <10). But I'm still trying to figure out how to implement it recursively.

Comment: @Metro101 wait, it works iteratively? Now that's interesting, is that something fundamental or just a coincidence?

Comment: I think it's just a coincidence, for small n-s it doesn't get into the edge case of running out of primes that start with a particular digit so it doesn't need to backtrack. It would be interesting to find out up until which n it works though.

Answer (score 0):

I just made a list of the two-digit prime numbers, then solved the problem by hand; it took only a few minues. Not every problem requires a computer!